# Debugger Showing Element Not Visible Without

Tags: javascript

In my website, whenever a user types a command, a loading circle shows. The way this happens is with the jquery command

```
$("#load").show()
```

But the problem is that the loading circle bar only shows when I have a debugger and am looking at it in inspect. Here are some photos:
[image: The Element in Inspect with a debugger (the loading circle in the input text)]

Then without the inspect element, the loading bar doesn't show. HELP PLEASSE!!!

Comment: Probably something else is hiding it. When you use the debugger, you're stopping between those two operations, so you see the loading circle.

Comment: Yeah, thats the problem, I can't figure out what is hiding it, even after going step by step through the events.

Comment: I've seen this before.  If you are doing too much processing in the browser, it never gets around to updating the UI.  You need to show your loader in a different thread by spawing it either as a promise, or more simply, as a settimeout function with one millisecond.

Comment: @JohnLord Thank you so much John, that answered my question! (a 1 millisecond delay worked)

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this before. If you are doing too much processing in the browser, it never gets around to updating the UI. You need to show your loader in a different thread by spawing it either as a promise, or more simply, as a settimeout function with one millisecond.

```
setTimeout(() => {  $("#load").show(); }, 1);
```